# Error: No named parameter with the name 'child'

Tags: flutter, dart

[plz solve this the red score under child](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oFKrz.jpg)

plzzz solve this[the red line under child name](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2eje8.png)

Comment: listview widget got only children https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ListView-class.html. You don't need a child for this. Can you elaborate on what was the need for the child here?

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to fetch data using API, then using ListView.builder is right, but `ListView.builder` does not have property named `child`. It uses `itemBuilder` property to populate data.

But if you are trying to use it to design your page, then I suggest using `Column`.

Answer (score 0):

ListView.builder doesn't take child as parameter. List items are supposed to be return from itemBuilder function. And numbers list items will be determined by integer you passed on itemCount parameter.